# Crontab and script

Tags: python, linux, cron, sh

I have debian linux. I've created from user `crontab -e` this text:

```
0   * * * * python /home/user/CronLogic.py
15  * * * * python /home/user/CronLogic.py
30  * * * * python /home/user/CronLogic.py
45  * * * * python /home/user/CronLogic.py

*/1 * * * * date > /tmp/TEST
```

Last string runs fine but running python script fails with:

```
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/rcssserver: not found
```

The code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
cmd ='/usr/bin/rcssserver'
err = open('CronLogicERRORS', 'a')
server = subprocess.Popen(cmdRes, shell=True, stderr=err)
```

And the error appears in `CronLogicERRORS` file. What could be wrong here? Without cron script runs fine.

Comment: Python variable is `cmd` but `cmdRes` passed to subprocess. Might be worth avoiding shell in subprocess?

Comment: Well, judging by the given example, Python is not really needed at all. Maybe the OP doesn't show the whole Python script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cmd ='/usr/bin/rcssserver'
#                ^^^ Too many s's
```

Now, about your `cron` usage:

Instead of having the same line 4 times, make it one line of `0,15,30,45`, or even better `*/15`.  And your `*/1` is redundant, just plain `*` is better.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I wrote that this script runs ok withour cron ;) Name of binary is accurate.